# T-test for not normalized data

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, t-test

I have to compare time-series data from two years and want to observe if specific measures are different.
My data set is not normalized, and its completely left skewed (for both years). (No normalization possible)

My Question: Can I use the t-test to compare the two datasets, when there skewness is nearly the same for both datasets?
If not, what test can I use?

Comment: t-tests are for independent data, while you have a time series?

Comment: Yes I have time-series data